# C# - Parse Process.StartTime to a certain format

Tags: c#, datetime

I can't figure a way to parse a Datetime object that is "10/24/2022 4:01:35 PM" to "24/10/2022 16:01:35".

Can't find an answer for this exact format.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ParseExact` + `ToString` ... asked multiple times(I do not have link to duplicate)

Comment: There is no parsing to be done. You parse a string to a DateTime. If you already have a DateTime then there's nothing to parse and it has no format. If you need a string then you call ToString. That's it, that's all.

Comment: If what you have is a `DateTime` object and what you want is a string representing that `DateTime` value in a specific format then you're just looking for `ToString()` with format specifiers.  It's not really clear to me where you're stuck.  Can you provide a specific example of your attempt and indicate what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Please show relevant code, as your question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need to parse that string to `DateTime` since you have it already in [`Process.StartTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.starttime?view=net-6.0) and you're looking at it in the debugger. Then use it directly. If you really have it as string you simply need to use `DateTime.Parse` with `InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("10/24/2022 4:01:35 PM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and for the output:

```
Console.Write(dt.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```